# Making directories list first in terminal with `ls`

Tags: terminal, macos

Is it possible to make the default of Terminal such that when I use the `ls` command it lists the directories first and then the files?

I figured out that this can be done by using `coreutils` and the command `gls --group-directories-first`, but I was wondering if there was an OS X native way to do this without `coreutils`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. The `ls` shipped with OSX is not the GNU `ls` therefore it doesn't have the same options.

But you can get a similar result with :

```
ls -al | sort -k1 -r
```

Ps: I agree that it's far from perfect :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think there would be a shortcoming of using `gls` instead of `ls` in any situation?

Comment: I'm using gls (with an alias on ls) for 2 or 3 years right now. It never has been problem.

Comment: AFAIK, `gls` will miss some [extended file attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) as the builtin ls. For example, '/bin/ls -d ~/Dropbox' reports `drwx------@` while 'gls -d ~/Dropbox' reports `drwx------` for the permission field.

Comment: How do add color to folder name with this command?